# Getting 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' with PDFDocument initWithData?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, printing, pdfdocument

I'm using [jsPDF](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html) in a webview to generate a PDF that I'd like to print out on a connected USB label printer. I'm getting a 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error.

Here is the error from the Xcode console:

```
-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1089cb868
```

Here is the function for reference:

```
- (void) printPDFwithPrinter: (NSString *) printerName andData: (NSData *) data{

    NSLog(@"%@", printerName);

    PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];

    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    [printInfo setTopMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setBottomMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setLeftMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setRightMargin:0.0];
    [printInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [printInfo setPrinter:[NSPrinter printerWithName:printerName]];

    PDFPrintScalingMode scale = kPDFPrintPageScaleDownToFit;

    NSPrintOperation *op = [pdfDocument printOperationForPrintInfo: printInfo scalingMode: scale autoRotate: YES];

    [op setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
    [op setShowsProgressPanel:NO];
    [op runOperation];
}
```

The pdf data is the raw output of the pdf body as a string. ([Docs](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output))

I'm brand new to Objective-C, so I'm using [AppBurger](http://juancamiloestela.github.io/AppBurger/) for my Native/webview bridge (building my app in HTML/JS/CSS).

**Here is my Xcode project so far:**
https://github.com/josiaho/AppBurger-Print-Test

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete and exact error message.

Comment: Can you also show the code that generates the `NSData` object from which you call your `printPDF:` method?  There's no `bytes` function on a `NSString`, b.t.w.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I've added a repository with the entire Xcode project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to debug:

1. Add a breakpoint on the line
   PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];
2. Test the app. When the app hits the breakpoint, inspect `data`.
3. `data` is a `NSString` and `initWithData:` expects `NSData`.

How to fix:

1. Rename

`- (void) printPDFwithPrinter: (NSString *) printerName andData: (NSData *) data`

to

`- (void) printPDFwithPrinter: (NSString *) printerName andString: (NSString *)  string`

2. Convert `string` to `NSData`.

`NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

3. Test the app.